# Create proxy class that redirects between two objects

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

Here's what I'm trying to Accomplish: At run time, I want to create a dynamic class that will override any class T. The idea is: The generated class will Hold 3 objects of Type T (One which I call Original, other which I call Modified, and other one which I call Active, with this one switching between these two.

Now, my generated class shoudl also extend T, whereas any of it's virtual properties will be overriden (both getter and setter) and will redirect to the same property of the Active object it holds.

My difficulty is: How do I access a property of the object Active? Here's my code:

```
public static Type CompileResultType<T>()
    {
        //Gets Type builder that extends type T
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder<T>($"{typeof(T).Name}Proxy");
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

        //Add Active field
        FieldBuilder activeFieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("Active", typeof(T), FieldAttributes.Public);

        //Add Original field
        FieldBuilder originalFieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("Original", typeof(T), FieldAttributes.Public);

        //Add Modified field
        FieldBuilder FieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("Modified", typeof(T), FieldAttributes.Public);

        //Get all public properties of type T
        var allProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //Get all virtual properties
        var filteredProperties = allProperties.Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && p.GetSetMethod().IsVirtual);
        foreach (var property in filteredProperties)
            CreateProperty<T>(tb, property.Name, property.PropertyType, property);

        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
        var teste = tb.GetFields();
        return objectType;
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder<T>(string typeSignature)
    {
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Mask.Builder");
        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.Public | 
                                                                TypeAttributes.Class | 
                                                                TypeAttributes.AutoClass | 
                                                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | 
                                                                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | 
                                                                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, typeof(T));
        return tb;
    }

    private static void CreateProperty<T>(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType, PropertyInfo activeProperty)
    {
        //THE PROBLEM LIES HERE: Trying to access the respective property of object Active, but doesn't work
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("Active." + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        //Create Getter that will retrieve "Active.PROPERTY"
        MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


        //Create Setter that will write into "Active.PROPERTY"
        MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual, null, new[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
        Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

        setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
    }
```

Comment: I did this sort of thing once. Then I discovered that once you get it, it becomes rather boring and you find there are [well maintained alternatives](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-introduction.md) that make life much easier.

Comment: Abstraction might become your enemy later on.

Comment: I have implemented this with DynamicProxy from castle core, but the call to each property is slow and I was tasked to optimize this.

Comment: Of course it is slow, you have generic types mixed with reflection.

Comment: That's why I wanted to go to this solution which will be faster.

Comment: @greg. There's nothing slow about generic types. Now, reflection, that's a different story

Comment: @Flydog57 I mostly meant the reflection, then coupling them together with generic's is asking for performance issues.  Because the generic is acting on the anonymous type, but you are correct.